Azure DevOps SQL DacPac deployment not working with Service Connection
For one of our clients I'm configuring a build and deployment pipeline in Azure DevOps for an Azure SQL database. We have done this many times before without issue, but this is the first time I'm using a service connection of the type "Workload identity federation".
I've modified the YAML code as required and connected the variable groups to the pipeline but I keep getting the following error:

There was a resource authorization issue: "The pipeline is not valid. Job deployment_job_prod: Step input azureSubscription references service connection DEVOPS_mdwh_connection_prod which could not be found. The service connection does not exist, has been disabled or has not been authorized for use.

Since the name of the service connection is correct and configured based on variables in the variable groups, I know that those can be accessed. Pressing the "Authorize resources" button next to the error message doesn't seem to do anything. I've tried changing the AuthorizationType in the YAML script to servicePrincipal, WorkloadIdentityFederation or just disabled it, but that doesn't seem to make a difference either.
I'm at a bit of a loss here. Microsoft recommends using Workload Identity Federation over service principals now so I'm reluctant to change back to that. Can anyone here help me figure out what I'm missing? Below is the YAML code that's being used as well as the service connection settings:
- name: env
  displayName: Environment
  type: string
  values:
    - tst
    - acc
    - prod
- name: ServiceConnectionPrefix
  displayName: Service Connection Prefix
  type: string
- name: SQLDatabaseName
  displayName: SQL Database Name
  type: string
- name: SQLProjectName
  displayName: SQL Project Name
  type: string

jobs:
  - deployment: deployment_job_${{ parameters.env }}
    displayName: Deployment Job ${{ parameters.env }}
    environment: Deploy to ${{ parameters.env }}
    variables:
      - group: 'VG-MDWH-${{ upper(parameters.env) }}'

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - checkout: self
              displayName: 1. Retrieve repository

            - task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
              displayName: 2. Deploy DACPAC
              inputs:
                azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.ServiceConnectionPrefix}}${{ parameters.env }}'
                ## AuthenticationType: 'WorkloadIdentityFederation'
                ServerName: '$(ServerName)'
                DatabaseName: '${{ parameters.SQLDatabaseName }}'
                deploymentType: 'DacpacTask'
                DeploymentAction: 'Publish'
                DacpacFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/${{ parameters.SQLProjectName }}/${{ parameters.SQLProjectName }}/bin/debug/${{ parameters.SQLProjectName }}.dacpac'
                PublishProfile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/${{ parameters.SQLProjectName }}/${{ parameters.SQLProjectName }}/${{ parameters.SQLProjectName }}_${{ parameters.env }}.publish.xml'

Service connection settings:

As you can see here there are no restrictions on the service connection either:

Any help would be appreciated.

Since the name of the service connection is correct and configured based on variables in the variable groups, From your description, the service connection name is configured by the variables in the variable group. But from the YAML sample, azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.ServiceConnectionPrefix}}${{ parameters.env }}' the azure subscription field is using parameters. Can you explain this point more clearly?

Sorry, I should have made that more clear. This yaml template is actually called through another file which is actually triggered by the pipeline. This main file uses a variable group to get the serviceConnectionPrefix and Environment values. These are then passed as parameters to the yaml file that actually does the deployment. But I can see in the error message that the full name of the service connection is correct so that's not where the problem is coming from.

Yes. Totally agree. The parameters value should be correct. You can check if the service connection is valid. I have shared the steps in the answer. You can check it.

The solution was about as stupid as you can get. I left a space in front of the ServiceConnectionPrefix variable. Removing the space also solved the problem... I will now hide in shame for a decade...

We all have our shameful moments, don't worry about that :-)


Since the name of the service connection is correct and configured based on variables in the variable groups

TL;DR Service connection names cannot be stored in variable groups. Declare them as variables in your YAML pipeline or template instead.
Also, remember to queue at least one build manually in order to authorize any service connection(s).
More details
Variables in variable groups are available at runtime so they are only available after a pipeline starts.
Given that a service connection is a protected resource that needs to be authorized before the pipeline starts (i.e. at compile time), we cannot use variables from variable groups. Only values that are available at compile time can be used.
Example
/pipelines/variables/dev-variables.yaml
variables:
  - name: azureSubscription
    value: dev-service-connection

  # other dev variables here

/pipelines/variables/qa-variables.yaml
variables:
  - name: azureSubscription
    value: qa-service-connection

  # other qa variables here

/pipelines/variables/prod-variables.yaml
variables:
  - name: azureSubscription
    value: prod-service-connection

  # other prod variables here

my-pipeline.yaml
jobs:
  - deployment: deployment_job_${{ parameters.env }}
    displayName: Deployment Job ${{ parameters.env }}
    environment: Deploy to ${{ parameters.env }}
    variables:
      - template: /pipelines/variables/${{ parameters.env }}-variables.yaml # <------- reference variables template here
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - checkout: self
              displayName: 1. Retrieve repository

            - task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
              displayName: 2. Deploy DACPAC
              inputs:
                azureSubscription: ${{ variables.azureSubscription }} # <------- from variables template referenced above
                # other inputs...


Thanks for your answer. I think I may have forgotten to mention that this template is called by another template, which is actually the one triggered by the pipeline. This main template reads variables from a variable group, such as the serviceConnectionPrefix and environment. These are passed to the SQLDeploy.yml as parameters. Since the connection name is correctly stated in the error message I know the parameters are passed properly with the right values. We've set up this kind of pipeline many times, the only difference is the use of the workload identity federation.


here was a resource authorization issue: "The pipeline is not valid. Job deployment_job_prod: Step input azureSubscription references service connection DEVOPS_mdwh_connection_prod which could not be found.

From the error message, it shows the service connection name: DEVOPS_mdwh_connection_prod. This means that the parameters have passed the correct value to the azureSubscription field. The parameters in the YAML file should be correct.
The cause of the issue could be that the service connection itself is not valid.
In this case, it will show the same error.
For example:

When you use the Workload identity federation type service connection, it has not verify option when editing the service connection.
You can use the following steps to check if the Workload identity federation type service connection is valid.
Step1: Manually search the sql task in YAML UI editor.

Step2: You can select the sql task and check if you can see the DEVOPS_mdwh_connection_prod service connection in the service connections dropdown list.

If you cannot see the service connection in the dropdown list, this means that the service connection itself is not valid.
To solve this issue, you can navigate to Project Settings -> Service Connections and create new automatically Workload identity federation type ARM Service connection in Azure DevOps UI and check if it can work.

Or you can try to create a manually Workload identity federation type ARM Service connection. For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: Manually set an Azure Resource Manager workload identity service connection
Note: AuthenticationType field in SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1  is used to control Azure SQL server connections. It is not related to azureSubscription field and not support WorkloadIdentityFederation value. Refer to this doc: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1 - Azure SQL Database deployment v1 task

Thanks for the detailed explanation Kevin. However, when I try to create the SQL task I can see the service connection just fine.

@KoenvanWielink Can you confirm how to create the Workload identity federation type ARM Service connection? On UI or use Rest API or other methods? Then I can do further test.

If possible, can you try to manually create an automatically Workload identity federation type ARM Service connection in Azure DevOps UI (Project Settings -> Service connections)?

In addition, you can also try the following two methods: 1. Edit the name of the existing service connection and save it. 2. Create a new Pipeline using the same yaml file and check if it works.

The service connection was created using the UI in DevOps using the Workload Identity federation (automatic) option. Unfortunately I don't have the user rights to create a new connection or alter the existing one. Altering the name gave the error "
One or more issues occurred while trying to rotate service endpoint secrets. More details: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation in Microsoft Graph." I'm discussing with the IT provider if they can temporarily grant me the necessary access.

@KoenvanWielink Yes. The error message means that you don't have permission. You can contact the admin to check if they can grant your permission or help you do operation.

On the other hand, you can try to hardcode the service connection name in the existing pipeline or create a new pipeline with the same YAML file. Then you can check if it can make some changes.

I found the issue but I'm almost too ashamed to admit it. Your idea of hardcoding the connection name finally pointed me in the right direction. I accidentally put a space in front of one of the variable names in the library... I will now book a one way ticket to Nepal and hide as a monk in a monastry for about a decade...

@KoenvanWielink No Problem. This is indeed a very hidden issue. But I am glad to know that the issue can be resolved now!
